# Como acessar uma variável dentro de ngAfterViewInit() no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Já procurei aqui no stack mas nao encontrei a resposta. Alguém sabe se dá para acessar uma variável que está dentro do de ngAfterViewInit() no Angular.

No código abaixo, na última linha quando tento atribuir a variável `motivo` para `motivoTitulo`, a ide me informa que "Não é possível encontrar o nome 'motivo'".

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const controlBlurs: Observable < any > [] = this.formInputElements
    .map((formControl: ElementRef) => Observable.fromEvent(formControl.nativeElement, 'blur'));

  const self = this;

  let motivo: string;

  this.swal.showSwalConfirmText(function(confirmacaoMotivo) {

    if (confirmacaoMotivo) {

      motivo = confirmacaoMotivo;
      self.removerTitulo();

    } else {
      self.cancelar();
    }
  });

}

motivoTitulo = motivo;
```

Comment: por que vc não move essa linha pra dentro do afterviewinit?? No javascript e na maioria das linguagens só vão existir dentro de seu escopo por exemplo uma função

Comment: obrigado @EduardoVargas .. é pq preciso usar essa variável em outra função dentro desse mesmo componente.  Na função que vou usar, eu tento atribuir a variável mas vem como undefined:  `let tituloHistorico = new TituloHistorico();


            tituloHistorico.motivo = this.swal.motivoTitulo;`

Comment: this.algumacoisa = coisaquesoexistenafuncao;

Comment: Ué, mas por que você não declara a variável **motivo** fora do `ngAfterViewInit()` se você quer usar o valor atribuído nela fora do viewInit?

Comment: @EduardoVargas tentei com `this.motivo = confirmacaoMotivo;` fora do ngAfterViewInit() mas diz que "Não é possível encontrar o nome 'confirmacaoMotivo'"

Comment: @LeAndrade entao cara, eu tentei atribuir com `motivo = confirmacaoMotivo; ` fora do NgAfterViewInit()  mas diz que "Não é possível encontrar o nome 'confirmacaoMotivo'."

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta e inserir como deve ficar seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa sua questão independe de Typescript é o que é chamado de escopo sendo o básico de **Javascript**. Você não consegue acessar variáveis ou seus valores declaradas fora do escopo onde foram criadas. Repare que no exemplo abaixo a variável `fora` pode ser acessada tanto dentro quanto fora da função já a variável dentro pertence ao escopo da função, não podendo ser acessada do *"lado de fora"* da mesma

```js
var fora;                                                           // <- VARIÁVEL GLOBAL

function Teste () {
  var dentro = 'RECEBE DENTRO E SÓ PODE SER UTILIZADA DENTRO !!';  // <- VARIÁVEL INTERNA
  fora = 'RECEBE DENTRO E ARMAZENA O VALOR FORA !!';
  
  console.log(dentro);
  console.log('02 -', fora);
}

Teste();

console.log('01 -', fora);
console.log(dentro);  //  <- ERRO POIS NÃO É VISIVEL FORA
```

Com relação ao seu código:

```
public motivo: string;           // fora do ngAfterViewInit()

ngAfterViewInit() {
   const controlBlurs: Observable < any > [] = this.formInputElements
   .map((formControl: ElementRef) => 
      Observable.fromEvent(formControl.nativeElement, 'blur'));

   const self = this;

   this.swal.showSwalConfirmText(function(confirmacaoMotivo) {

     if (confirmacaoMotivo) {

        this.motivo = confirmacaoMotivo;         // <- atribui um valor aqui
        self.removerTitulo();

     } else {
        self.cancelar();
     }
   });

}
```

> Desta maneira **this.motivo** fica visível para qualquer função dentro da classe.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver simplesmente seu problema, vc pode fazer dessa forma:

```
    export class BlaComponent {
  public motivo: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const self = this;
    let motivo: string = 'blz';

    this.bla.x(this.fazAlgumaCoisa(motivo, self));
  }

  fazAlgumaCoisa(confirmacaoMotivo: any, self: any) {
      return (confirmacaoMotivo: any, self: any) => {
          self.bla = 'x';
      }
  }
}
```

Mas sua classe tem alguns problemas, por exemplo, a atribuição do motivo está fora do método 'afterViewInit';

E por exemplo, você pode colocar as variáveis no escopo da classe, e criar um outro método de classe, que o typescript vai saber qual 'this' utilizar.

Na duvida, use o playground do typescript:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html